# How to get UITableViewCell to fit entire TextView, regardless of size of text?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to display a text field in each table cell. The problem is I cannot seem to get the UITableViewCell to be tall enough to fit the whole TextView. The UITableViewCell does not need to be dynamic, as the data is loaded into the UITextView on the view's load.
Here is my code:

```
//
//  chatViewController.swift
//  collaboration
//
//  Created by nick on 11/21/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class chatViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    var messages: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    var authors: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection Section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.authors.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! chatTableViewCell
        cell.authorLabel?.text = self.authors.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let receivedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("usernameToMessageWith")
        testLabel.text = "\(receivedUsername! as String)"
        authors.addObject("")
        authors.addObject("You:")
        CGRect frame = messagesTextView.frame;
        frame.size = messagesTextView.contentSize;
        messagesTextView.frame = frame;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this. Please do not make fun of me for my pathetic screwed up scope attempt.

Comment: If the text is not editable use a UILabel.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a textField you have to calculate the height programatically and set it when displaying your cell. If it's not editable however you can do the following with a UILabel.

In you `viewDidLoad` set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <expected height>` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

In your custom cell you then need to set layout constraint for the top and bottom of the UILabel towards the edges of the contentView and set `UILabels lines` to `0`

Possible workaround for textfield:

Use both a textfield and a UILabel and set the UILabels text color to clear color. This way you can use the UILabel to adjust the height but still have the functionality of the text field also.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <expected height> 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

will only work for **iOS > = 8**
If you want to make the code compatible for **iOS 7.x** too you can try the code below.
As suggested instead of textview or textfield use **UILabel** if text is not editable. Here is a workaround to calculate the height with **UILabel**.

Provide the name of the font which you are using and the size of the font used exactly the same. which you have kept.

```
func requiredHeight(text:String) -> CGFloat{
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height + //Add some space as a part of your bottom and top constraint
}
```

Suppose your label has top and bottom constraint as 10 and 10 respectively, them make the return statement as:

```
return label.frame.height + 20
```

Call this method in **heightForRowAtIndex** and pass the text there as a parameter. It will return a dynamic height based on the calculations.

**EDIT**
How to use

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return requiredHeight("Your text")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, your function looks like it has a lot of potential. I did  few Google searches and was unable to come up with any information regarding how to use heightforRowAtIndex method. Do I just put heightForRowAtIndex(requiredHeightVar) in the viewDidLoad() or tableView method? Thank you

Comment: put  this method in tableView's heightForRowAtIndex like 
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return requiredHeight("your dynamic text to be displayed")
}`

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath is the tableView datasource method that you need to use in your view controller class. Check edited answer